# Inline Skates: Slalom / Parallel Turns Skidding Heel Brake

Tags: inline-skating

On my inline skates the heel brake is on the right foot.  When I turn right with the slalom / parallel method, the heel brake sides catch the ground and limit my tilt angle of my blades.

The brakes are already adjusted to be as high off the ground as possible.

Am I doing something wrong?

Blades: https://www.rollerblade.com/products/macroblade-80-abt-2/

Comment: The heel brake is an assist to  new skaters who are learning how to stop properly.  Most skates allow you to remove it once you've learned how to hockey stop, snow plow stop, and t-stop.

Comment: Thanks, I removed them a few weeks ago.  Removing them doesn't seem like it's necessary for other blades with heel brakes as I've seen plenty of people skating outside with them on and are still able to do parallel turns.  Could it just be the ABT design has a lower to ground design?